# What's going on in my BIOS re:M TPM Module

Tags: tpm

I have a gigabyte GA-P55A-UD4P motherboard. When I bought the motherboard it came with a small pamphlet titled "Step-by-Step Smart TPM User's Manual" so I presumed that it had an onboard TPM installed or at least a socket for one. I have decided to enable bitlocker so I got out the pamphlet and went to step one "Configuring the System BIOS." I was surprised when, in the CMOS Setup Utility, I received the following two messages:
1. Security Chip Disabled (no surprise); and
2. Security Chip Disabled/Deactivated (surprise).
I tried to navigate through the menu but it was locked out. I suspect that means that there is no TPM unit on my motherboard. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes; You would have to purchase one;

Answer (score 0):

According to both Gigabyte's [GA-P55-UD4P rev. 1.0](http://www.gigabyte.com.au/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3160#sp) and [GA-P55A-UD4P rev. 2.0](http://www.gigabyte.com.au/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3435#ov) pages, `TPM function is optional due to different regional policy`. That makes it sound like most boards don't come with it. I can see that there's a [special manual for using TPM with that board](https://www.manualowl.com/m/Gigabyte/GA-P55-UD4P/Manual/207517). If this manual didn't come with the board, I suspect you have the version without TPM.